# Discord banner changing sends static image instead of gif

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, gif

I want my discord bot to change banner every 20 seconds with current members count, but my method sends static image instead of gif. This is example of code with command setbanner instead of every 20 seconds to change:

```
@commands.has_role(settings.PROGRAMMER_ROLE_ID)
@client.command(name='setbanner')
async def setbanner(ctx):
    banner = Image.open(settings.BANNER_LOCATION)
    gif_bytesio = BytesIO()
    banner.save(gif_bytesio, format='GIF')
    gif_bytesio.seek(0)
    await ctx.message.guild.edit(banner=gif_bytesio.read())
```

I think there is an error in my way to translate GIF image to BytesIO

It isn't working with just GIF image because it doesn't have .read() method, and without read method it says 'File' object has no attribute 'switch'.

Comment: Just to make sure: Does your server have enough boosts to set a GIF as a server banner? Did you hover over the image to see if it's really static?

Comment: yes, for sure, 3 lvl of server and I checked if image is static in settings of server(there it is always animated)

Comment: I mean when I put the gif with discord app it is animated in settings, but with bot command it is static

Comment: @sndmndss, check if the GIF is valid. Also, check if `BANNER` is there in [`guild.features`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.features). If it's not there, please tell so. And it's from https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.edit#:~:text=This%20is%20only%20available%20to%20guilds%20that%20contain%20BANNER%20in%20Guild.features. Check if your GIF to bytes conversion works as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idk why, but the problem is in BytesIO.

I remembered one more way to convert in bytes:

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=20.0)
async def set_banner():
    guild = client.get_guild(settings.GUILD_ID)
    helpers.GifEditor(settings.BANNER_LOCATION, settings.EDITED_BANNER_LOCATION, guild)
    #creates edited banner
    with open(settings.EDITED_BANNER_LOCATION, 'rb') as file:
        banner = file.read()
    await guild.edit(banner=banner)
```

Here it is ;)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).